# Switch to mobile view of stackexchange

Tags: discussion

When I first opened this site on phone (opera mini on android) mobile view opened, then I switched to original view using the link at bottom.
Now how do I switch back to mobile view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old way, today not functioning any more:

Just append "mobile/on" to the base URL of the SE site you want to have mobile skin re-enabled

The new and official way as it is today:

click on the link "mobile" in the footer of the page

Comment: More information about the new Stack Exchange mobile theme here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98215/stack-exchange-mobile-theme-beta-starts-now

Comment: This no longer works. You need to click the 'mobile' link in the page footer now.